# Select from a list of items, using their foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making a music database and when I select an artist, I want a list of their albums to show up. Therefore I need to only select items with the foreign id matching the artists id (Album.ArtistID == Artist.ID), to show up in the view. How would I do this? Also, if you could explain why for learning purposes.

Method in controller:

```
public ActionResult AlbumIndex(int? id)
        {
            return View(db.Albums.ToList());
        }

public class Artist
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }

public class Album
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Artist")]
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Release Year")]
        public string ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
```

the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MusicECommerce.Models.Album>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <img class="image" src="@Url.Content(item.Picture)" />
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Songs)
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Pass the artist id to your action method parameter and use that to filter the Album data(Use `Where` method). Where are you stuck at ?

Comment: `return View(db.Albums.Where(x => x.ArtistID == id);` (but not sure what you want to do if `id` is `null` -display all?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke worked perfectly and yes, I've had that bit sorted already. much appreciated!